# Django saving updated database values from form

Tags: python, django

I am trying to allow a user to edit their profile. In the post method I want to save the new data over the old data in the same row.

```
# Post method of class view in views.py
def post(self, request, username):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404('The User "' + username + '" could not be found.')

    if (not request.user.is_authenticated):
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
    elif (user.id is not request.user.id):
        return HttpResponseForbidden()

    form = self.form_class(request.POST)

    if (form.is_valid()):

        # creates a new user object, does not save to the database yet
        profile = form.save(commit=False)

        # clean (normalized) data
        # ...
        profile.save()

        if (user.is_active):
            return redirect('/profile/' + user.username)

    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'error_message': 'Oops, something went wrong'})
```

This code I believe is creating a new database row when the post method is called. How do I get it to update the existing row in a clean looking solution?

Comment: There's no need to enclose `if` conditions in parenthesis in Python. It contradicts every Python style and looks ugly. You should write: `if form.is_valid():`, `if user.is_active:` instead. This way all Python code is written. If you read Django tutorial and Django docs you'd also notice that samples from official Python/Django documentation never wrap conditions in parens.

Comment: Also, first 4 lines in your code could be replaced with `get_object_or_404(User, username=username)`. Man, just start with Django tutorial and docs, it'll pay off better than asking trivial questions on SO.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Django's `UpdateView` then it takes care of a lot of these details with saving the ModelForm.. including saving the update, redirecting the user upon success, and redisplaying the form with errors shown if there's a problem.